# Unable to configure NLog Logging in MVC 6 ASP vnext starter project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nlog

Added to project.json file for logging:

```
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog":  "1.0.0-beta1"
```

The Framework.Logging.NLog depends internally upon NLog, which I tried installing via Nuget, project.json, Package console. It doesn't help.

Also wasn't able to find a way to configure NLog logging and a tutorial/guide to place the config sections of NLog.

Comment: For these types of questions it is often most helpful to post the contents of the `project.json` file. If the answer below doesn't help, that's what we'll need to see.

Answer (score 1):

NLog does not ship for CoreClr hence you need to define the dependency under aspnet50. Do look at the sample https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/project.json

Comment: [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.NLog](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.NLog) and [Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog) are currently not on NuGet.  Do you know if this is the only way to get NuGet with .Net 5?

Comment: Not being able to get the package may be related to https://github.com/aspnet/Home/pull/1034

Comment: We are working on CoreCLR support http://nlog.userecho.com/topic/935284-support-coreclr/

Comment: There is now a nuget package, including CoreCLR support (alpha) see: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging / https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging