# How to configure NLog to get IP address .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I develop .net core app and use **NLog** as logging framework.

How can I setup NLog layout to get remote IP address?

Unfortunately, `${aspnet-request.serverVariable=remote_addr}` isn't supported by **NLog.Web.AspNetCore**.

May be I can get access to `httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` somehow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is supported since NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.4.0.

1. Install the package  [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore)
2. Set in your config

   ```xml
   <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
   <extensions>
     <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
   </extensions>
   ```
3. You could now use `${aspnet-request-ip}` in your config.

PS: also supported for ASP.NET in NLog.Web 4.5.0

### Old answer

Currently this is not supported, but you could inject it in NLog like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using NLog.Web.Internal;

namespace NLog.Web.LayoutRenderers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Render the request IP for ASP.NET Core
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code lang="NLog Layout Renderer">
    /// ${aspnet-request-ip}
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    [LayoutRenderer("aspnet-request-ip")]
    public class AspNetRequestIpLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
    {

        protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            var httpContext = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            builder.Append(httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Register it (startup.cs)

```cs
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers
    .RegisterDefinition("aspnet-request-ip", typeof(AspNetRequestIpLayoutRenderer));
```

See also [Extending NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending%20NLog)

usage

```
${aspnet-request-ip}
```

Also include NLog.Web.AspNetCore!

Comment: Very helpful! There are important tib-bits in the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679727/use-nlog-in-asp-net-core-application/34888186) that should be looked at, too. Especially if your `HttpContextAccessor` keeps coming up `null`

Comment: Updated, as this is now supported out-of-the-box

Answer (score 3):

It is now easier:
Introduced in NLog Web.AspNetCore 4.4.0 & NLog.Web 4.5.0

Render Client IP address

Supported in ASP.NET & ASP.NET Core.

Configuration Syntax

${aspnet-request-ip}

Nothing else is needed

Answer (score 0):

Also it's needed to call the `.NLog()` before `.Build()`.

Something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  CreateWebHostBuilder(args).UseNLog().Build().Run();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simpler solution might be to use NLog's [Global Diagnostics Context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer) option.

For example, set a custom value named "IpAddress" before logging an event:

```
 public IActionResult AnAction()
 {
     NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("IpAddress", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);
     _logger.LogInformation("Something happened");
     return View();
 }
```

And in your nlog.config file, you can make use of that value in the layout like this:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\nlog.log" 
    layout="${longdate} | ${message} | ${gdc:item=IpAddress}" />
```

Comment: What happens with your global context if you have multiple users at the same time? Are you then sure that you are logging the correct IP-address. Maybe consider saving the IP-address into HttpContext.Current.Items, and then retrieve it using NLog ${aspnet-item}