# Log server details like IP address using nlog

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I have been trying to log server details using nlog. But seems like there is some errors in layout renderer.

I have tried these:

```xml
<parameter name="@serverName" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />

<parameter name="@port" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />

<parameter name="@serverAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />

<parameter name="@remoteAddress"  layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}" />
```

These are from official documentation but still these are not working.

[Official Github project link](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target)

I have these in project.json file

```
  "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rtm-beta1",
  "NLog.Web.AspNetCore": "4.3.0",
```

Comment: which line is getting error ?

Comment: Do you have included NLog.web?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. And yes I have included NLog.web in my project.json file

Comment: got it working?

Comment: I have used GlobalDiagnosticsContext and passed the value I required to the layout for now!! U got any better solutions!!

Answer (score 1):

As stated [in the docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-layout-renderer), the `serverVariable` option for `${aspnet-request}` isn't supported in ASP.NET Core

> serverVariable - ServerVariables item to be rendered. See for possible options: msdn. Not supported in ASP.NET Core.

There isn't a Server Variables collection in ASP.NET Core (in contract with ASP.NET), so we cannot use it.

We have replaced several constructions with new renderers, see [this overview](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-layout-renderer)

- `${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}` => Is this `${aspnet-Request-Host}`?
- `${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}` => `${aspnet-request-url:IncludeHost=false:IncludePort=true}`
- `${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}` => I think - `${aspnet-request-url}`
- `${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}`=> don't think this one is supported.

Update: if you need the IP, see [How to configure NLog to get IP address .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786220/how-to-configure-nlog-to-get-ip-address-net-core/40793174#40793174)

Comment: Not of all of this is correct eg: ${aspnet-request-url:IncludeHost=false:IncludePort=true} will return this https://:{portId}/{Rest of called path}