# NLog 5.0 with .net Framework 4.7.2 - aspnet request renderers are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

Using NLog 5.0, NLog.Web 5.0 and NLog.Database 5.0.  I am attempting to log the aspnet request variables as described in the documentation.  I log everything else just fine. Here is the code to setup the logger.  I also included the internal log file which I had set to Trace.

```
 var config = new LoggingConfiguration();;
 DatabaseTarget dbTarget = new DatabaseTarget()
        {
            ConnectionString = connString,
            DBProvider = "sqlserver",
            Name = "database",
            CommandText = "sp_insert_log",
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@browser", "${aspnet-request-useragent}"));
        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@ip_address", "${aspnet-request-ip}"));
        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@url", "${aspnet-request-url}"));
        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@message", "${message}"));
        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@level", "${level}"));
        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@stack_trace", "${stacktrace:format=DetailedFlat}"));
        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@exception", "${exception:format=tostring}"));
        dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@logger", "${logger}"));
     


        config.AddTarget("database", dbTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", ConfigHelper.CommonLogLevel, dbTarget));

        InternalLogger.LogFile = @"D:\logs\internal\" + ConfigHelper.InternalLogFile;
        InternalLogger.LogLevel = ConfigHelper.InternalLogLevel;
        InternalLogger.IncludeTimestamp = true;           
       

        LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = ConfigHelper.ThrowNlogConfigExceptions;
        LogManager.ThrowExceptions = ConfigHelper.ThrowNlogExceptions;
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

In a controller Action:
....

```
try
{
   //...attempt stuff
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   var CommonLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
   CommonLogger.Error(ex);
}
```

....

Trace output from the internal log:

```
2022-07-06 15:11:32.6517 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2022-07-06 15:11:32.6517 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout ' => '
2022-07-06 15:11:32.6517 Trace  Scanning Property LayoutRenderers 'NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer[]' System.Collections.Generic
2022-07-06 15:11:32.6517 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7450 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Open connection.
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7450 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Executing StoredProcedure: sp_insert_log
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: **'@browser' = ''** (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: **'@ip_address' = ''** (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: **'@url' = ''** (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: '@message' = 'System.Exception: Extended data test' (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: '@level' = 'Error' (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout ' => '
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace  Scanning Property LayoutRenderers 'NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer[]' System.Collections.Generic
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: '@stack_trace' = '[System.Object Execute(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase, System.Object[])] => [System.Object lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase, System.Object[])] => [System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Login(MyApp.Application.DTO.UserLoginDTO)]' (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: '@exception' = 'System.Exception: Extended data test
   at MyApp.Web.Controllers.LoginController.Login(UserLoginDTO dto) in MyApp\MyApp.Web\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 31' (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: '@logger' = 'MyApp.Web.Controllers.BaseController' (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.7520 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: '@extended_data' = '' (String)
2022-07-06 15:11:32.8397 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Finished execution, result = 1
2022-07-06 15:11:32.8397 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Close connection (KeepConnection = false).
```

Database Results:
[image: Aspnet request variables empty]

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled it in the config as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/40793174/43846

Comment: Where is a code that does  INSERT to the database (executenonquery)?

Comment: @stuartd It's a .net framework mvc application not asp.net.core.  So I'm only using Nlog.Web - are you saying I need both? NLog.Web.AspNetCore and NLog.Web then?

Comment: @jdweng It's a stored procedure setup in the database target: CommandText = "sp_insert_log", CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure.  Also edited post to show how it logs with a simulated try catch block.

Comment: The write to the database is done with a ExecuteNonQuery.  Just before the method the values are written to the parameters.  All I see is the parameters being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enabled the NLog InternalLogger as the first thing (Before `new LoggingConfiguration()`), then you would probably see why it fails.

If you enabled ThrowConfigExceptions as the very first thing, then you would probably get a nice exception:

```
NLog.LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true;
```

I'm guessing the problem is that you have not registered the NLog.Web-extension before using them in `DatabaseParameterInfo`:

```
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(s =>s.RegisterAssembly("NLog.Web"));
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component

Comment: @Rofl Thank you, never thought that the order in which I put them in the code would matter, apparently in this case it does.  Thank you for the info as that did the trick. All I did was add the RegisterAssembly before creating the config and all is well.  I didn't see I had to do that manually (new to NLog 5.0).  ~Cheers