# Dependency of NLog Version 4.4.0 not compatible with .netcoreapp version 1

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm in the process of trying to add logging to a .net core web api project, however when adding nlog v 4.4.0, I am getting an error indicating that it's not compatible with .net core v1 when I know it is.

Could someone tell me which portion may be causing the issue in the project.json file?

```
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
"NLog.Config": "4.4.0",
"NLog": "4.4.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.4.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/) as today.

[image]

It seems that you are using old way of creating .Net Core app which uses `project.json`. New one uses `.csproj` file.

[Migrating .NET Core projects to the .csproj format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/)

Answer (score 0):

For .Net core you need NLog 5 (beta). See also http://nlog-project.org/2016/10/30/nlog-roadmap-netcore-structural-logging.html

For setting up, see [Use NLog in ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679727/use-nlog-in-asp-net-core-application)