# NLog .NET Core 2 Log() does not accept LogEventInfo as argument

Tags: c#, nlog, .net-core-2.0

I'm implementing NLog with .NET Core 2 according to https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2 that uses these 2 packages:

- NLog 4.5.0-rc03
- NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.5.0-rc2

The logging works fine, but now that I want to add [Event Properties](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer), the Log() function does not accept LogEventInfo as an argument.

Any thoughts would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read -> https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging

Comment: Please show some code. How is the logger defined?

Comment: @RolfKristensen exactly what I needed. I must have overlooked that doc. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

When using ASP.NET Core, you have two options to use NLog.

You could use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (MEL), the logging abstraction is introduced by Microsoft. Then you can't use NLog types, like the `LogEventInfo` as the logging abstraction doesn't know NLog.
 For this you need the package [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore). See setup: [Use NLog in ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679727/use-nlog-in-asp-net-core-application/34888186#34888186)

Another option is to use NLog direct, so with the `LogManager` from NLog. Then you could use `LogEventInfo`.

See also [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging Vs. NLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209076/microsoft-extensions-logging-vs-nlog/58210510#58210510)

You could also add custom LogEvent-properties using MEL-ILoggerProvider (without using NLog LogEventInfo directly):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging