# Why everyone using logger packages with ILogger of ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

for logging, developers use from logging package like: Nlog, SeriLog , ...
while asp.net core has `Microsoft.Extenstions.Logging.ILogger` ?

doesn't `ILogger` of asp.net core recording log?

if `ILogger` can records log, isn't better uses that without any other packages?
if `ILogger` can records log, then why developers don`t use it alone?

and if `ILogger` can't records log alone and other packages do, then what is benefits of `ILogger` that being used with other logging packages together instead using one logging package alone?

Comment: `ILogger` is just an interface. You can use the frameworks' own interfaces, but then your app is "locked in" to those. Meaning, it is a high effort to change logging framework later on. If you use MS `ILogger` interface, you can easily back it by any framework that suits your requirements and change it later on with low effort, because all you need to change is some lines in your Dependency Injection Config and create a suitable logger config.

Comment: For example while `ILogger` is designed around structured logging [ `Log.LogDebug("MyVar is {Something}", myVar)` vs `Log.LogDebug($"MyVar is {myVar}")`], it doesn't actually support it natively (essentially performing a string format). You can take a framework that does support structured logging such as Serilog and use it to *back* the `ILogger` without having to change the interface you are coding against.

Comment: related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209076/microsoft-extensions-logging-vs-nlog/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default ASP.NET Core using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`.

So call CreateDefaultBuilder, which adds the following logging providers:

- Console
- Debug
- EventSource
- EventLog: Windows only

code example:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                 {
                     webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                 });
```

source: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

So generally speaking every project has its own requirements and needs, so the developer can choose which one is more fit to project needs.
Other logger providers like Nlog, SeriLog , Asure, ...
can provide different log themes, flexible configurations, log in to file, and other features that the default ASP.NET Core not have.
The ILogger and ILoggerProvider interfaces and installation of additional packages have the flexibility to add other logger providers.

ILoggerProvider Interface
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Hope I`m answered well.

Comment: thanks for answer. then asp.net core doesn't has native logger to use without any packages? for this , we either use logging packages  or write custom logging framework.
i'm  right?

Comment: Your welcome, AspNetCore provides the console log, so you right you need to install or write your own packages.

Answer (score 2):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> .NET Core supports a logging API that works with a variety of built-in and third-party logging providers. This article shows how to use the logging API with built-in providers.

This gives you flexibility and additional features.