# C# global logging

Tags: c#, logging

I'm writing a program and writing my own logging at the moment but I would like to start using a library.  Does the common logging library in C# allow for 1 logger that is shared globally?  I have multiple classes and I would like them all to log into 1 file without passing some reference of the logger into each class.  Also would this be good practice if possible?

```
class myclass1{

    //declare logger here...

    funca() {
        log("run status");

        myclass2 mc = new myclass();
        mc.funcb();
    }
}
```

another file.

```
class myclass2{

    funcb() {
        //don't need to pass logger reference just log here.
        log("run status");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line

Answer (score -1):

You can use [NLog](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#Best-practices-for-using-NLog). All details are in the link. If you are using asp.net core, you can use [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Here is the SO for [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209076/microsoft-extensions-logging-vs-nlog) between Nlog and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

Comment: Is dependency injection the term im looking for for sharing the same logger accross multiple class

Comment: Nlog you don't need.

Answer (score -2):

Ended up going with Serilog, simple syntax and didn't have to redeclare logger in new class.

```
class myclass1{

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("logs/myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();

    

    funca() {
        Log.Information("Hello, world!");

        myclass2 mc = new myclass();
        mc.funcb();
    }
}
```

another file

```
class myclass2{

    funcb() {
        //don't need to pass logger reference just log here.
        Log.Information("Initialized test class!");
    }
}
```