# ${aspnet-request-posted-body} not returning data

Tags: nlog

hi I am trying to use Http target to send the log to an API.

nlog.config:

```xml
<targets>
   <target name='HTTP'
        type='HTTP'
        URL='https://localhost:44331/api/logs'
        Method='POST'
        BatchSize='1'
        MaxQueueSize='2147483647'
        IgnoreSslErrors='true'
        FlushBeforeShutdown='true'
        ContentType='application/json'
        Accept='application/json'
        DefaultConnectionLimit='2'
        Expect100Continue='false'
        UseNagleAlgorithm='true'
        ConnectTimeout='30000' 
        InMemoryCompression='true'>
            <layout type='JsonLayout'>
                <attribute name='sourcetype' layout='_json' />
                <attribute name='host' layout='${machinename}' />

                <attribute name='RequestBody' layout='${aspnet-request-posted-body}' />
                <attribute name='event' encode='false'>
                    <layout type='JsonLayout'>
                        <attribute name='level' layout='${level:upperCase=true}' />
                        <attribute name='source' layout='${logger}' />
                        <attribute name='thread' layout='${threadid}' />
                        <attribute name='message' layout='${message}' />
                        <attribute name='utc' layout='${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}' />
                    </layout>
                </attribute>
            </layout>
    </target>
```

I got every attribute I added except for RequestBody.
Also logging to file and database is working fine as well as
 http it is being called but without the request body data.
Any thing I am missing?

Comment: The same as GitHub ;) without platform (asp.net, asp.net core) and versions of used platforms and NLog components this just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're missing the proper setup.

I will list the options:

### ASP.NET (non-core)

You need to have the package [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nlog.web) installed

Then it should work out of the box, but I you have still issues, then force to include NLog.Web like this:

```xml
<nlog> 
  <extensions> 
    <add assembly="NLog.Web"/> 
  </extensions> 
  ...
```

See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#extensions)

#### ASP.NET Core

For ASP.NET Core it depends on the version.

First of all you need the package [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nlog.web.AspNetCore) installed.

Also add to your config:

```xml
<extensions>
   <!--enable NLog.Web for ASP.NET Core-->
   <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

And the Setup need to call NLog.Web.AspNetCore. I would recommend to check: [Use NLog in ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679727/use-nlog-in-asp-net-core-application)

Make sure you have called `.AddNLogWeb();` / `.UseNLog()` (dependent on the ASP.NET Core version)

### Still issues?

Still issues? There could be various other reasons and for now that's guessing. The target you used could choke on the length of the value etc.

I would recommend: Test it with a [FileTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target) or [ConsoleTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target) 
and as [check the internal log](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging)! - that will show a good error message if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same and solution is in few github issues and thanks to Julian.

1.https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/548

```
FilePath=C:\Users\user\myapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\nlog.development.config
2020-07-21 11:05:29.1792 Warn Exception in layout renderer. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at NLog.Web.LayoutRenderers.AspNetRequestPostedBody.BodyToString(Stream body)
   at NLog.Web.LayoutRenderers.AspNetRequestPostedBody.DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer.RenderAppendBuilder(LogEventInfo logEvent, StringBuilder builder)
```

2. https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/549
3. https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/556

Adding below finally fixed the issue.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next();
});
```

to here and Must be before app.UseEndpoints

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

Comment: Add where? What position?

Answer (score 1):

[NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.1](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/781) changes [${aspnet-request-posted-body}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-posted-body-layout-renderer) so it requires middleware to work:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware>();
```

The middleware will ensure `context.Request.EnableBuffering();` is called when necesary, so one doesn't have to call it explictly.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/HTTP-Request-Logging